# Problem with java script calling with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ipad

when i use document.title i am getting data

```
NSString *theTitle=[[[featuredAsset viewControler]iWebview]stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

if i print theTitle

Data in theTitle is present working fine......

I need to get data for getElementById

its printing nothing.......

```
NSString *theTitle=[[[featuredAsset viewControler]iWebview]stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var field = document.getElementById('searchType');"];
```

data in theTitle is empty

Comment: Why are you assigning to a variable?

Comment: printing value inside the varable.

Comment: I meant the assignment `var field = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the following javascript code:

```
@"var field = document.getElementById('searchType'); return field.value;"
```

or whatever property you need evaluating from `field`.

EDIT:

Make sure that you execute this method only *after* `webViewDidFinishLoad` has been called (otherwise your DOM may be incomplete) and that your `'searchType'` object actually exists, e.g.:

```
@"var field = document.getElementById('searchType'); alert(field.value); return field.value;"
```

Comment: its not getting any value sir.